# Why is a negative y coordinate going up even though the upper part of a cartesian plane is both a y and a positive?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

In the sample code below:

```
Private Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim Testobj As Graphics
    Testobj = Me.CreateGraphics
    Testobj.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Panel1.Left - 1, Panel1.Top - 1, Panel1.Width + 1, _ Panel1.Height + 1)
End Sub
```

A button click causes a panel to have a red border, but if you look at `panel1.top` its set to -1 with top being the top part of the border of the panel also known as the y part and it produces this output
[image: test_image1]

but if I set it to a positive value.

[image: test_image2]

the red border of the top part goes down, even though images of a cartesian plane says that a y going up(or a y going positive) makes the red border go up.

Am I missing anything?

it's also the case for a program called game maker studio. so I strongly think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Windows Forms coordinates are measured from the top, left corner. X increases going to the right and Y increases going down.

Comment: (This is pretty common for computer graphics/layout.)

Comment: By the way, while many lazily-written tutorial examples do it for convenience, you should NEVER call `CreateGraphics` in real code. Any time you want to draw on a control (a form is a control too) you should do so in the `Paint` event handler or `OnPaint` method and use the `graphics` object supplied. It is VERY important that you understand that because calling `CreateGraphics`, while useful for simplicity, is almost always BAD in an application, especially when you don;t dispose the `Graphics` object you create.

Comment: so basically its the same as how humans drag windows going bottom right?
computers do the same?
I guess I'll hold on to the logic on computers flipping the cartesian plane vertically .